# Animating MenuItem in Android ToolBar

Tags: android, android-animation, navigationbar, objectanimator

How would I be able to animate a menuitem by translating its X coordinate to off screen on Android. I've looked at Property Animation and ObjectAnimator, both of which don't seem to be able to work. Does anyone have any idea?

```
<menu xmlns:yelp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    yelp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_bar_map_icon" />

</menu>
```

Comment: What's wrong with Property/ObjectAnimators? They should be able to animate the translationX property.

Comment: @MarcinKoziński Problem is Drawables do not have a setTranslationX property so ObjectAnimator is not able to invoke the change.

Comment: @MikeM. I actually mean't a tool bar. I'm unable to cast the drawable to the ImageButton though. This is how I'm doing it. ImageButton hamburger = (ImageButton) toolbar.getNavigationIcon(); 

I set the NavigationIcon using toolbar.setNavigationIcon(Drawable) fyi

Comment: @MikeM. I'm doing a bunch of random experiment, and found ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(hamburger, "alpha", 0, -90); to work. But setting the "translationX" property doesn't... Hamburger is of type Drawable too

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks so much for the help! That solved my problem with navigationIcon. Do you by chance know how this would work with a menuItem? Since that is not a imageButton anymore.

Comment: @MikeM. So I have another item in a Menu that I'd like to animate. This menu item is specified in an xml and inflated in the the class I want to perform animations in. It looks something like the following, (please see the edit )

Comment: @MikeM. I don't think these belong to the same toolBar. I get the toolbar via "Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) support.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);" but I inflated the menuItem using "support.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);" in onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: @MikeM. java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView

Comment: @MikeM. From what you're saying, it seems like every menuItem belongs to a specific view? what if the menuItem is just declared like the above xml, what is the view holding that specific "map" menuItem?

Comment: @MikeM. I think you're talking about menu in the toolbar, whereas I'm talking about a standalone Menu that's inflated